# Livechart winforms solidgague thickness problem

Tags: wpf, winforms, graph, gauge, livecharts

I want to change circle thickness inside the solidgauge.[is that possible to change this thickness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwbw6.png)
please help me thanks everyone.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwbw6.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `Gauge.InnerRadius`  property:

```
<Gauge Height="150" Width="150"
       From="0" To="1" 
       Value="0.5" 
       InnerRadius="60" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked how i want !